# "Вместе взятых": отделяется ли запятой

Tags: пунктуация

"В нем было сил больше, чем в них троих, вместе взятых". Я что-то засомневалась: нужна тут запятая после "троих" или нет?
Спасибо

Answer (score 5):

Из Розенталя: 
Оборот "вместе взятое" в разных формах всегда обособляется, например: "Всё это, вместе взятое, убеждает в правильности принятого решения. В этих сборниках, вместе взятых, содержатся сотни упражнений". В приведенных примерах обособление оборота, действительно, не вызывает сомнений.

Тем не менее в текстах встречаются варианты, в которых оборот "вместе взятое" входит в другой обособленный оборот, и тогда его не всегда можно обособить,например: (1)Созданный Пушкиным  рисунок Востокова более содержателен, нежели все его портреты вместе взятые, созданные профессиональными мастерами. (2)На самом деле, Пушкина в Маяковском было больше, чем во всех классицистах вместе взятых.

В приведенном примере оборот также лучше бы не обособлять: "В нем было сил больше, чем в них троих вместе взятых". В этом случае при отсутствии паузы оборот является смысловым центром второй части предложения, что соответствует содержанию всего высказывания. Но доказать правильность такого  решения весьма затруднительно, поэтому  экзаменационные тексты лучше писать по Розенталю.