# Всё(,) вместе взятое

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужны ли запятые в этом предложении?

"Всё(,) вместе взятое(,) порождает в нас так называемое туннельное мышление".

Я знаю, что в справочнике Розенталя есть следующее: "Оборот ***вместе взятое*** всегда обособляется: *Всё это, **вместе взятое,** убеждает в правильности принятого решения; В этих сборниках, **вместе взятых,** содержатся сотни упражнений*". (В справочнике Лопатина я не нашел этого сочетания.)

Но, во-первых, в одном из этих примеров добавлено "это", а в другом тоже не такая структура. Во-вторых, меня смущает категоричное "всегда обособляется". Ведь если зайти на сайт kartaslov.ru, на который здесь довольно часто ссылаются, то там собрано по 50 предложений, [с запятой](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91%2C+%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5) и [без нее](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91+%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5) (видимо, они ограничились этим количеством).

Так что с этим делать? Все-таки можно и так, и так, то есть в зависимости от того, рассматривает ли автор это сочетание в качестве причастного оборота или как нечто нераздельное, хочет ли он выделить его интонацией или нет?

Comment: Нужен контекст в каждом случае. Тогда можно проверить стилистику и поставить знаки. На первый взгляд именно в этом предложении не хватает слова "это". (Я уж не будо говорить почему.)

Comment: @Sharon  "Ограниченность нашего восприятия и неспособность наших органов чувств во всей полноте получать то, что существует в мире, дополняются упрощенностью ума и накоплением множества страхов и душевной боли. Все вместе взятое порождает..."

Comment: Да, я думаю, что слово "это"  желательно здесь использовать (сравните прочтение двух вариантов и выберите подходящее). А в общем случае оба варианта возможны. Вот пример из Нацкорпуса:  «Они в миллионы раз ценнее, чем нефть, газ и всЁ, вместе взЯтое, потому что создают устойчивость глобального климата». Здесь компактное расположение обобщающего слова «всё». (Оно употреблено в значении существительного.)

Comment: Это как бы устойчивое сочетание. Нельзя добавить "что": *Всё, что вместе взято, порождает...*

Comment: @oleedd, про устойчивое да, я тоже отметил это в вопросе, только другим словом. А про "что" не понял... так как нигде его нельзя добавить, даже там, где запятые стоят.

Comment: Смотрю, что в других случаях "что" успешно добавляется, например: *Всё, связанное с железной дорогой (что связано с железной дорогой)...* Это говорит об устойчивости. А устойчивость говорит о возможности написания без запятых. Розенталь тоже тупил, пару раз бывало. А про это уже спрашивали: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/31288 София — очень умный отвечающий.

Comment: @oleedd, я говорю именно об этом сочетании: "всё(,) вместе взятое".  Ха, не подумал, что такое здесь обсуждалось, спасибо за ссылку!

Comment: Часто надо сравнивать с другим, чтобы разобраться.

Comment: Нельзя сказать, что язык не меняется. Вот это вот утверждение было написано 65 лет назад.

Comment: @oleedd Розенталь (если это он, а не редакторы) не тупил, просто у него не было доступа в Нацкорпус, как у вас.

Comment: @Sharon В Нацкорпусе хаос. Он на классиков ориентировался. Может, он считал, что без дополнительных слов нельзя.

Comment: Он на газету "Правда" ориентировался, наверное. Этот оборот характерен для газетного стиля. А у вас другие информационные возможности

Comment: Только публицистический.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ограниченность нашего восприятия и неспособность наших органов чувств во всей полноте получать то, что существует в мире, дополняются упрощенностью ума и накоплением множества страхов и душевной боли. **Всё(,) вместе взятое(,) порождает в нас так называемое туннельное мышление.***

Предлагается: ***Всё это, вместе взятое**, порождает в нас так называемое туннельное мышление.*

**Пояснение**

1. Оборот речи  «***всё вместе взятое***» может рассматриваться как единое сочетание. В этом случае  слово «всё» является **местоименным существительным** с неопределенным значением, а причастный оборот находится в постпозиции относительно этого местоимения, является **смысловым центром** всего сочетания и не обособляется (это известное правило письма, так что устойчивость оборота можно объяснить).
2. В примерах из литературы встречаются следующие  формы: ***(1) всё вместе взятое, (2) всё, вместе взятое, (3) всё это, вместе взятое.***

Выбор нужной формы завит от структуры предложения и расстановки ударений:

*Для меня, человека успешного, **все вместе взЯтое** было ударом невероятной силы.*

*Они в миллионы раз ценнее, чем нефть, газ и **всЁ, вместе взЯтое**, потому что создают устойчивость глобального климата.*

***ВсЁ это, вместе взЯтое,** подводит к мысли, что Зельдович не ведал, что творит, когда пытался «втянуть Ландау еще в какие-то задачи».*

3. В приведенном предложении предлагается использовать форму  «***всё это, вместе взятое***». По смыслу оборот обобщает однородный  ряд членов **из контекста**, поэтому желательно наличие **указательного** местоимения.

**Примечание.** Оборот без обособления «***всё это вместе взятое***» также встречается в литературе, хотя в справочнике Розенталя он не рекомендуется. Надо сказать, что эта форма также выглядит вполне корректной (тот же смысловой центр).

*Многоголосый шум, приглушенные стоны, работающие двигатели грузовиков, отрывистые команды распорядителей, слепящее горячее солнце… ― **все это вместе взЯтое** быстро накрыло Александру удушливой волной сонной одури.*

[Розенталь, пункт 4](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146996/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: 1) "Все вместе взятое" всегда обобщает однородный ряд. Иначе и быть не может. Мы же должны понимать, что имеется в виду под "всё". 2) Устойчивость к смысловому центру отношения не имеет.

Comment: У вас проблемы с логическими связями. Вы часто неправильно используете "так что" и "поэтому". Проблемы с логикой дают о себе знать... Прокачивайте...

Answer (score 2):

Помнится, у Розенталя есть примечание о том, что причастный оборот, стоящий после определяемого слова, выраженного определительным, указательным или притяжательным местоимением, не отделяется запятой от этого местоимения. Пример: Все отобранные для выставки картины будут экспонироваться.

Comment: Да, это я видел как раз в этом же пункте, в 4-м (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108). И там говорится также о возможном обособлении, если определительный оборот имеет характер пояснения или уточнения. Меня же интересовал именно оборот "вместе взятое". Спасибо.

Comment: А чем Вас заинтриговал причастный оборот "вместе взятое"? Нормальное выражение, имеющее склонность к устойчивости употребления.

Comment: Прежде всего категоричностью обязательного обособления в справочнике. Ну и в связи с этим пунктуация в конкретном предложении.

Answer (score 1):

Из прочитанного я бы сделал такой вывод:

Если все/всё/всех - местоимение, - то запятая не нужна.

Если все - [наречие, предикатив,](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91#:%7E:text=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%2C%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%3B%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5.) - то нужна.

Вопрос: как собственно понять, местоимение это или наречие, предикатив?

Вообще, то что показывает карта слов, что изначально писалось без запятой, запятая появилась позднее. И, кстати, не всегда после *всё/все*, а бывает "все вместе, взятое":

> А **все вместе, взятое в совокупности,** ― понятия, физические законы, формулы, их выражающие, и следствия из них ― называют обычно наукой. Л. Пономарев. Атомы, лучи, кванты // «Химия и жизнь», 1969

Запятую начинает ставить, например, Салтыков-Щедрин, после перечисления:

> Лицо у него было благородное, манеры благородные, образ мыслей
> благородный, но в то же время **все, вместе взятое,** внушало уверенность...

**Лицо** - *благородно* - раз, **манеры** - *благородные* - два, **мысли** - *благородные* - и всё(условие/предикатив - первое, второе и третье), вместе взятое, внушало уверенность. **Оценка, оценка поведения, расчёт** - выраженные в предикативе *благородно*, выражение благородства в лице и прочем. Лицо - благородно? Лицо было благородно - да. Выполненное условие. **Всё - благородно - наречие**.

Но запятую ставили далеко не всегда:

> **Новизна** стиля, **качество** звука, **мощность**, **разнообразие** смычков, между тем, легкость, >с которою он все исполнял, ― меня все это так поразило, что **все вместе взятое** >вполне завладело мною... Н. И. Бахметев. Записки и дневник (1887)

Чувства, впечатления, то есть ОНО(бессознательное) - не расчёт.

> В ярком блеске горячего полдня **все вместе взятое** ― **народ в
> праздничных одеждах** по крутым скатам, **синевшая** даль, **клокочущая** вода,
> цветы, сыпавшиеся отовсюду по пути Великого Князя ― представляло
> картину в полном смысле слова великолепную.

ОНО - полнота смысла, впечатление, - не расчёт. Не народ - а народ-в-праздничных-одеждах, не даль - а клокочущая-даль. Образы.

> Рядом он занимается самоусовершенствованием и самовоздержанием. Это все, вместе взятое, поддерживает его дух и не дает погибнуть.

Перечисление методов - расчёт, не даёт погибнуть - мотивация. Это **всё - для** поддержания духа.

Расчёт и оценка имеют цель - **для**. Цель дробит целостное чувственное восприятие на рациональные сегменты, потому запятая.

> Постановка довольно реальна, исключая мест, где говорит толпа: вместо
> обычного в таких случаях шума, хаоса голосов раздаются равномерно в
> такт произносимые целым хором слова ― точно рубят их и тем немало
> нарушают иллюзию. Само собою разумеется, что **все, вместе взятое**, может
> удовлетворить только наивный, невзыскательный вкус и неприхотливую
> публику, зато действие на эту последнюю очень сильно. Верещагин.

Оценка происходящего, цель - удовлетворить публику... Публика всё - удовлетворена, предикатив.

> И, стало быть, **они** не просто семья или соратники, но **все**
> вместе взятое и скреплённое одинаковым пониманием смысла жизни и своим
> отношением к подлости и злобе.

Отношение к подлости, злобе смыслу жизни - общие смыслы, Они и Оно-всё - местоимение.

> Все вместе взятое(Оно) позволяет **китам**(Им) из года в год приходить в одни и те
> же районы, а в некоторых случаях даже в определённые заливы и бухты.

Оно - местоимение, киты считать не умеют.

> Дим, на тебе разведка, ты с этим справляешься **лучше** нас **всех** вместе
> взятых. Константин Муравьёв, Тени павших врагов, 2019

А вот тут я бы поставил запятую, потому что **лучше всех** - наречие, оценка. Как скажем тут, где есть запятая, что правильно:

> Да я старше их всех, вместе взятых! Таисия Альбертовна Цой, Вселенные. Сборник рассказов, 2020

Далее опять по старенькому:

> И все вместе взятое ― хорошо поставлено и красиво.  Василий Катанян. Лоскутное одеяло (1960-1969)

Ну не нужна тут: хорошо, красиво - впечатление. А вот если бы было *красивее* - то все, вместе взятое.

> ...а тут один ребёнок **стоил** их **всех, вместе взятых**.

Ну понятно...

> Даже низший уровень потерь – это больше, **чем все вместе взятые расходы**
> государства на здравоохранение, науку, образование, культуру и
> искусство за любой бюджетный год.

Ошибка, очевидно. Чем - уже сравнение, все - предикатив "взятые".

> Каждый из них, порознь уходя в отпуск, не представлял себе, как это выглядит **все, вместе взятое,** какая лавина людей... Константин Симонов. Живые и мертвые (1955-1959)

Расчёт, оценка будущего, все верно. И он же:

> Тут, наверное, **было все вместе взятое**: **и страх**, что вдруг
> откуда-то выскочит на меня японец, а я ничего не смогу сделать, и просто мальчишеское **желание** идти с наганом в руке, как ходили другие.... Константин Симонов. Далеко на востоке (Халхин-гольские записки) (1948-1968)

Впечатления - запятая не нужна.

> И эта маленькая деревня, и это большое кладбище, и несоответствие между тем и другим ― **все, вместе взятое,** потрясло душу Синцова. Константин Симонов. Далеко на востоке (Халхин-гольские записки) (1948-1968)

Деревня, кладбище и их несоответствие - это не **страх и желание**, а область объективной оценки, поэтому запятая. Главное слово деревня, а не Эпитет, эпитета нет, есть оценочные прилагательные - маленькая, больше, несоответствие маленького и большого.

Почему ставится запятая?

То есть **предикатив** - это **критерий отбора по ряду признаков/условий**, которые составляют совокупность и включаются во "все".

В свою очередь "взятое" - тоже становится предикативом. Всё, взятое - запятая разделяющая предикативы.

Касательно "весь вместе взятый". Насчет запятой пока думаю, но для этой фразы характерно, что после неё обязательно идет прилагательное или притяжательное местоимение, а не определяемое слово.

> ..весь реальный мир вместе взятый..

Показательно, даже расстановка иная: весь - относится к реальный, весь реальный, а мир - вместе взятый.

> ..весь наш пыл, вместе взятый в троекратном размере..

*Скорее всего *весь вместе взятый* - это калькированный all together или taken together. А есть еще all taken together - который не переводят как весь. И вообще весь - это whole, то есть целый, цельный.*

Либо:

> весь вместе взятый цирковой коллектив - весь-цирковой, взятый вместе-коллектив.

А вот:

> Весь вместе взятый флот.

уже неточность, потому что какой флот - морской или торговый? Сразу вопрос к термину флот.

> Также и весь вместе взятый факультет.

Какой факультет, факультет чего? явная неполнота информации...

Насчет запятой, тут сложнее, потому что вариантов больше, но я бы не ставил. За исключением фраз выраженных через отрицание:

> Такого количества не имел весь, вместе взятый, остальной мир.

не имел весь мир, не вместе взятый, а остальной.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147009/discussion-on-answer-by----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Никакой не предикатив. Здесь форма "весь", а не чисто "всё". Вот правильная ссылка: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/весь

Comment: @oleedd вырази мысль, пожалуйста, полностью или напиши свой ответ.

Comment: Когда предикатив, нельзя изменить форму, а здесь можно: *всё вместе взятое, все вместе взятые*. Ну и пункты предикатива не подходят по смыслу. В ответе надо аргументировать, а не просто говорить.

Comment: @oleedd Почему, когда предикатив нельзя форму менять? Ты животное/ ты живой/ ты жив? Когда номинатив, мб форму менять нельзя, а когда предикатив - можно. Предикатив может и глаголом быть, и прилагательным, и наречием и свойством качеством, а номинатив - только существительное заменяемое на неопределенное местоимение Оно. Но может быть и Они - вместе взятые. Поэтому тут это не работает.

Comment: Потому что в тех примерах нельзя изменить форму.

Comment: @oleedd каких тех? местоимение мне понятно, но на что конкретно оно указывает?

Comment: Во всех словарных примерах (во всех словарях). Местоименное прилагательное. Вопрос "какие?".

Comment: @oleedd Во всех каких? во всех вместе взятых словарях что ли?) Если так, тогда не ясно почему писали то так, то сяк. И еще до создания этих самых словарей - Нацкорпус.

Comment: Да, во всех. К предикативу эти фразы отношения не имеют.

Comment: @oleedd опять набор категоричных утверждений через местоимения. Так мы далеко не уедем.

Comment: Доказывать вам надо, ответ ваш. Вы написали бред про части речи. А мне опять доказывать, что 2 + 2 ≠ 5.

Comment: @oleedd мне нужно угадать, что ты хочешь или что? что не так? конкретно, в чем проблема?

Comment: Проблема в начале ответа. В этих фразах только местоименное прилагательное. Никакого наречия и предикатива. И это разные части речи. Наречие и предикатив — это не одно и то же.

Comment: @oleedd ну да, потому что предикатив - это не часть речи.

Comment: Это спорно. https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/предикатив В ряде языков — **часть речи**, используемая **в качестве сказуемого**... Где вы здесь видите сказуемое?

Comment: Предикатив - это не часть речи, а функция определенной части речи, когда часть речи может выступать в роли сказуемого. В русском сказуемыми могут быть почти все части речи. Значит, почти все могут имеют функцию предикатив, но предикатив не обязательно сказуемое. Причастие и прилагательное также является предикативом, почти всегда, но не обязательно сказуемым. Предикатив - признак объекта, свойство. Ваня выбрал красное одеяло - Ваня выбрал одеяло или красное? Если одеяло, то красное обычное прилагательное, эпитет, а если красное - то это не эпитет, а предикатив. Условия выбора.

Comment: @oleedd короче предикатив, это то, что не подлежащие, а подлежащее, то что не предикатив. А вот сказуемое ли предикатив или что-то еще, это уже вопрос другой.

Comment: @oleedd также не каждое сказуемое - это предикат. Я ушел - нет предиката. Я ушел гулять - предикат "гулять". Всё - я ушел, - предикат всё. Предикат используется только для внешней речи, а внутренняя речь предикации не фиксирует, потому что внутренняя речь суть бред, бормотание, блуждание - то, где смысл не выражен явно, - предикат "явно".

Comment: @oleedd также в русском языке есть путаница, потому что главным считается определяемое слово - это красная лодка, главное слово лодка. А в английском главным словом будет предикат, потому что предикат имеет значение - this is a red boat. Это Лодка - красная! Это является красным и относится к лодкам. Поэтому в русском появляется тире: это - красная лодка. Это не лодка, а "красная", совсем уже не лодка, не вещь, а лодка-гиберно, термин. A red - артикль перед red, а не перед boat, это из красных. Как-то так.

Comment: В ответе ошибка. Предикатива (сказуемого "всё") в этих фразах нет.

Comment: @oleedd предикатив всё есть, предикатива в твоей фразе - нет.

Comment: Предикатива в ваших примерах с "всё вместе взятое" нет. Это просто как назвать слово "груша" прилагательным.

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий к ответу Буратино**

**ПРАКТИЧЕСКИЙ ВЫВОД** (начну с него, информативный стиль)

Выбор запятой мы можем сделать в сочетаниях ***всё(?) вместе взятое*** или ***всё это(?) вместе взятое*** («это» указывает на предыдущий контекст). Запятую ставим при логическом подчеркивании **местоимения** «всё», а при отсутствии запятой ударение переходит на **предикатив** «взятое».

**Выбрали, а дальше?** А вот дальше надо так построить предложение, чтобы наше сочетание «вписалось» в его структуру и сохранило эту расстановку ударений

**ОСНОВНАЯ ЧАСТЬ**

**Очень интересный, как всегда, разбор!** (голос от меня). Этимология, семантика (смысл), восприятие слов…  Можно соглашаться или не соглашаться с выводами, но вот чувство языка (слова!) удивительное и   безусловно **заслуживает внимания**.

Но в современном языке многое **меняется**, многое видится по-другому, а значения слов уточняется в **толковых словарях**.

Кроме того, знаки препинания –  **это три принципа,** а именно: на письме СЕМАНТИКА выражается через ГРАММАТИКУ и ИНТОНАЦИЮ.  Другими словами, не НАПРЯМУЮ, так что на ПЕРВЫЙ план выходит интонация и грамматика. Даже правила письма ориентируются прежде всего на грамматический принцип, в то же время в них есть замечания и по произношению.

А при наличии **вариантов** для одной и той же грамматики на первое место ставится ИНТОНАЦИЯ, которая **КОРРЕКТИРУЕТ** и уточняет грамматику. Также интонация является **основным средством связи** в БСП, где при отсутствии союзов выражает **смысловые отношения** между частями предложения.

Автору важно выразить ***семантику*** (как он понимает смысл), но для этого он должен выбрать нужную **форму** (грамматику, структуру, интонацию), чтобы читатель понял этот смысл. И здесь нужно не только правильно построить и выбрать знаки **в словосочетании** (*все это вместе взятое* или *все вместе взятое*), но важно подобрать нужную **структуру** предложения.

Ведь читатель не будет воспринимать **каждый фрагмент** по его смыслу. Будет учтено все, в том числе **расстановка ударений** в простом или сложном предложении.

Я говорю об **общей МОДЕЛИ** теории современной пунктуации (в кратком изложении). Впрочем, модель скорее **АВТОРСКАЯ (это всего лишь МЕТОДИКА, а вовсе не теория!!)**, но в то же время она **соотнесена с авторитетными источниками** по грамматике и правописанию.

Также очень важна реальная **ПРАКТИКА,** отраженная в литературе. Все ошибаться не могут и всех неграмотными не назовешь. Просто надо анализировать, выбирать, улавливать общую тенденцию. Там мы как бы видим "обобщенное мнение" наших современников, их **восприятие** речи.

**P.S.**  А моим вечным критикам (известно кому) предлагаю обзавестись собственной пунктуационной **моделью** (желательно тоже соотнесенной с источниками) и решать задачи в соответствии, а не только много и долго говорить.  Вот тогда и будет видно, **кто «правее»**))

Создайте "работающую модель", подтвердите ее эффективность на практике при решении задач на форуме, вот тогда это будет **честное соревнование.**

***Больше красивых и правильных решений!*** Ну и желательно решений, принятых авторами вопросов))